# .Net Core API to count item from database

Tags: c#, api, linq, asp.net-core

I'm trying to count Order from Database with API but it doesn't seem to work.
There's a message from Swagger that said `"Failed to load API definition. Fetch error undefined swagger/v1/swagger.json"`

This is in OrderController:

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(int))]
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> CountOrders()
    {
        int result = await _orderService.CountOrders();
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

This is in OrderService:

```
public async Task<int> CountOrders()
    {
        return _orderRepository.CountOrder();
    }
```

This is in OrderRepository:

```
public int CountOrder()
    {
        IQueryable<DataProvider.Entities.Order> orderList;
        orderList = GetAll();
        return orderList.Count();
    }
```

I'm new to this so please point out if there's anything makes you feel uncomfortable. Thanks.

Comment: That's an issue with swagger. Does your api return a value if you use another client, like postman? You should post your swagger config in `startup.cs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I was kind of stupid and didn't realise I haven't change the route, so it got duplicated.
It works after adding `[Route("count")]`